# Why doesn't this method work? Java ternary operator

Tags: java, ternary-operator

What's wrong with this code:

```
void bark(boolean hamlet) {
    hamlet ? System.out.println("To Bark.") : System.out.println("Not to Bark");
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ternary operators can't have statements that don't return values, `void` methods.  You need statements that have return values.

You need to rewrite it.

```
void bark(boolean hamlet) {
     System.out.println( hamlet ? "To Bark." : "Not to Bark" );
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can read why in the Java Language Specification, [15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> *It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.*

You need to do as several of the other answers suggest, and apply the conditional operator to just the argument.

Answer (score 4):

According to [§JLS.15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> ```
> ConditionalExpression:
> ConditionalOrExpression
> ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
> ```

> The conditional operator is syntactically right-associative (it groups
> right-to-left). Thus, a?b:c?d:e?f:g means the same as
> a?b:(c?d:(e?f:g)).
>
> The conditional operator has three operand expressions. ? appears
> between the first and second expressions, and : appears between the
> second and third expressions.
>
> The first expression must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a
> compile-time error occurs.
>
> **It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand
> expression to be an invocation of a void method.**

Comment: thanks for those links to the specs. I had never looked at them before.

Answer (score 1):

I should imagine its because the ternary operator is expecting to assign a value. Try this:

```
void bark(boolean hamlet) {
    String result = hamlet ? "To Bark!" : "Not to Bark";
    System.out.println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A ternary statement has to return something, you could use an if here:

```
void bark(boolean hamlet)
{
  if (hamlet)
  {
    System.out.println("To Bark.")
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.println("Not to Bark");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators must return something. So you can put it inside the print statement like such:

```
void bark(boolean hamlet) 
{
    System.out.printf("%s\n", hamlet ? "To Bark." : "Not to Bark");
}
```

Or:

```
void bark(boolean hamlet) 
{
    System.out.println(hamlet ? "To Bark." : "Not to Bark");
}
```

Comment: Why `printf` when Java standard and OP's use is `println`?