# ternary operator not working

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Netbeans is saying that my ternary operator isn't a statement. How come?

```
int direction;
direction = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 0 : 1; // direction is either L or R (0 or 1)
direction == 0 ? System.out.print('L') : System.out.print('R');
```

I tried it's if/then/else counterpart and it works fine:

```
int direction;
direction = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 0 : 1; // direction is either L or R (0 or 1)
if(direction == 0){
    System.out.print('L');
} else {
    System.out.print('R');
}
```

Comment: In Java, a 0 has no boolean representation. Only boolean expressions can be used for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this method work? Java ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876698/why-doesnt-this-method-work-java-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The statements in the ternary operator need to be non-void. They need to return something.

```
System.out.println(direction == 0 ? 'L' : 'R');
```

Answer (score 9):

A ternary operator is intended to evaluate one of two expressions, not to execute one of two statements. (Invoking a function can be an expression if the function is declared to return a value; however, `System.out` is a `PrintStream` and `PrintStream.print` is a `void` function.) You can either stick with the `if...else` structure for what you're trying to do or you can do this:

```
System.out.print(direction == 0 ? 'L' : 'R');
```

NOTE: The comment by @iamcreasy points out a bit of imprecision in how I phrased things above. An expression can evaluate to nothing, so what I should have said was that a ternary operator evaluates one of two *non-`void`* expressions. According to the [Java Language Specification §15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand
>   expression to be an invocation of a void method.

Comment: But according to [JLS 14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) MethodInvocation is an Expression Statement. So does it mean an expression can return void? (In general cases)

Comment: @iamcreasy - An expression can indeed be void (I wouldn't use "return void" because "return" has a specific technical meaning in JLS) but not in general cases, According to [JLS §15.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.1), the result of evaluating an expression can be a variable (akin to an _lvalue_ in C), a value, or nothing (a void expression). However, a void expression _"can be used only as an expression statement (§14.8), because every other context in which an expression can appear requires the expression to denote something."_

Answer (score 5):

From the JLS section `15.25. Conditional Operator ?`:

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.

both the second and third operand expression here:

```
direction == 0 ? System.out.print('L') : System.out.print('R');
```

are `void` so this is a not a valid use of a ternary expression. You could either stick to the `if else` or use something similar to this alternative:

```
System.out.print( direction == 0 ? 'L' : 'R' );
```

Also the logic here is not correct:

```
direction = (int)(Math.random() * 1);
```

`direction` will always evaluate to `0` since `Math.random()` generates numbers in the range `[0.0,1.0)` which means it does not include `1.0` and casting a `double` to `int` will just [drop the decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143476/how-to-cast-a-double-to-an-int-in-java). Using [`nextInt(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) is a good alternative.

Comment: +1 for the catch about the use of `Math.random()`. OP should be using `Math.random()*2` or creating a `java.util.Random` object and using `nextInt(2)`.

Comment: Yes, actually I caught that as soon as I tested the program. changed it to direction = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 0 : 1;